# One liner function to iterate over array of objects and change one value

Tags: javascript, iteration

Let's say I have an array of objects like this:

```
let x = [{'a': 0.288888, 'b': 0.5}, {'a':9.565464645654, 'b': 0.6}];
```

I want to iterate over this and change the number to fixed length. I tried

```
x.map((data) => data.a.toFixed(3))
# ["0.289", "9.565"]
```

Expected Output:

```
[{'a': 0.289, 'b': 0.5}, {'a':9.565, 'b': 0.6}]
```

One way to make it work would be:

```
x.map((data) => {
    data.a = data.a.toFixed(3);
    return data;
});
```

Is there any other/better way than this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `forEach` and mutate the existing object:

```js
const x = [{'a': 0.288888, 'b': 0.5}, {'a':9.565464645654, 'b': 0.6}];
x.forEach((data) => data.a = data.a.toFixed(3));
console.log(x);
```

This is doing the same thing that your `.map` is doing, in one line, but `.map` should only be done to create a new array - if you're looking for side-effects only, use `forEach`.

If you don't want to mutate and want to create a new array, then return a new object in the `.map`:

```js
const x = [{'a': 0.288888, 'b': 0.5}, {'a':9.565464645654, 'b': 0.6}];
const changedX = x.map(({ a, b }) => ({ a: a.toFixed(3), b }));
console.log(changedX);
```

If you're aiming for code readability (which is probably the most important thing for most scripts), I'd recommend *against* trying to squash everything onto one line - it doesn't make things more readable, often it's the opposite.

To make the first snippet pass the `no-return-assign` and `arrow-parens` rules, put brackets around the function body so that it's not a concise body:

```
x.forEach((data) => { data.a = data.a.toFixed(3) });
```

[Demo](https://eslint.org/demo#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)

Comment: Okay, your first solution works, but my ESLint throws error, `Arrow function should not return assignment.eslint(no-return-assign)`. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: You can put brackets around the function body so it's not a concise body: `x.forEach((data) => { data.a = data.a.toFixed(3) });`

Comment: Haha! Apparently, that's another ESLint violation.`Unexpected parentheses around single function argument having a body with no curly braces.eslint(arrow-parens)`.

Comment: You sure that's the error message from the code in the above comment? Doesn't make sense, because that function *does* have curly braces

Comment: If you're aiming for code readability (which is probably the most important thing for most scripts), I'd recommend *against* trying to squash everything onto one line - it doesn't make things more readable, oftenn it's the opposite.

Comment: Sorry, your second suggestion of putting curly braces results in the same message.`Arrow function should not return assignment.eslint(no-return-assign)`.

Comment: I still can't reproduce the problem - `return` isn't being used there, nor is anything implicitly being returned. See the demo link in the answer - are you sure you're using the same code I am?

Comment: Yes, I have tried your changes, and now it is giving `Assignment to property of function parameter 'data'.eslint(no-param-reassign)`. I checked out your demo and there is no error there. Sorry about previous comments, I must have messed up something there.

Comment: If you aren't allowed to reassign parameter properties, then `forEach` will not be usable for this, because `forEach` is for side-effects, but the side-effects you want are not allowed per the linter. It looks like a `for` loop doesn't throw that warning: `for (const data of x) {
  data.a = data.a.toFixed(3);
}` But it would be much better to use the `.map` technique

Answer (score 2):

Try using `forEach` loop

```
x.forEach((elem) => elem.a = elem.a.toFixed(3));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one-liner. Almost same as your `map` method call, But just use ({}) as return value to avoid explicit return statement.

```js
let x = [
  { a: 0.288888, b: 0.5 },
  { a: 9.565464645654, b: 0.6 }
];

const updated = x.map(data => ({
  ...data,
  a: data.a.toFixed(3)
}));

console.log(updated);
```

// with destructuring

```js
let x = [
  { a: 0.288888, b: 0.5 },
  { a: 9.565464645654, b: 0.6 }
];

const updated = x.map(({ a, b }) => ({
  a: a.toFixed(3),
  b,
}));

console.log(updated);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
let x = [
  { a: 0.288888, b: 0.5 },
  { a: 9.565464645654, b: 0.6 }
];
x = x.map(data => ({...data, a: data.a.toFixed(3)}));
console.log(x);
```